# Add Custom Font To MailChimp Design View Option

Tags: css, email, fonts, html-email, mailchimp

I've included the custom webfont font Asul into my MailChimp email template Code View using:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asul:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

However, in the Design View the font settings do not display Asul. The options only list the default fonts such as Arial, Comic Sans and etc.

[image: MailChimp Menu Options]

There is a kind of cheat that works as a failsafe taken from a [2010 article](http://blog.mailchimp.com/using-style-to-rock-some-socks/) at the MailChimp blog. The CSS is below.

```
/** Failsafe restores Asul Font
* @tab Header
* @section preheader text
* @style Asul
*/
.Asul{ 
/*@editable*/font-family: 'Asul', Arial, sans-serif;
/*@editable*/color:#FFF;
/*@editable*/font-size:12pt;
background-color:transparent;
border:none;
}
```

However, this is not a satisfactory solution. The above code creates an inline style and places it inside of a nested menu. The average user will have to be guided towards it's location. The image below displays this method.

[image: MailChimp Nested Font And Style Reset]

Is there a way to make this custom font show up in the Design View drop-down font list for selection instead of this nested approach? If so, how can I add it?

Comment: No, you added the HTML markup that creates the CSS font family for the font you want. Now you still need to tell your site that it should have "Asul" in its list of known usable fonts.

Comment: Yes, I need to tell MailChimp that this font is available in Design View. We've clearly established that now. An undesirable option I've found is create a style and reference it with `code` /** Asul Font
 * @tab Header
 * @section preheader text
    * @style Asul
    */
 .Asul{ 
 /*@editable*/font-family: 'Asul', Arial, sans-serif;
 /*@editable*/color:#FFF;
 /*@editable*/font-size:12pt;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
 }
    /*  `code` However, this produces an Inline style that is only accessible by hovering over the element and editing it directly - not in Design View.

Comment: So, taking into account Stackoverflow's guidelines on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), what does mailchimp's website and forums say about this?

Comment: Thanks for providing a link to the Stack Overflow guidelines on How To Ask A Good Question. That's extremely helpful. Especially helpful, given the amount of detail, code, tags and the image that I've provided in my intial attempt to outline this specific problem. Please note, the code included in my previous comment was taken directly from MailChimp's help forums and was originally written in 2010. Perhaps someone has tackled this particular issue in the ensuing 5 years?

Comment: perhaps they have, and that's why I linked you, because step one is "search, and research". Did someone run into this on Stackoverflow before? Did you search? what did you search for? Does Mailchip already cover this in their extensive "how to do X" documentation? If you don't know, you haven't looked. If you do know, what did you search for? It's not that your question is bad, but it certainly feels like you asked it before you checked in places that should have been checked first. And if you did, you forget to make this clear in your question so far.

Comment: On a practical note, since you mention the level of detail: perhaps I missed something: code-wise I only see a google webfont link, which isn't so much code as just "that's what google webfonts gives you to add to an html file", am I missing additional code that you changed to make sure the template knows about this new font?

Comment: Ah, speaking of "search and research" have you made time to review my first comment here? It's located after my question. In it I've clearly posted the undesirable code. It's frightfully difficult to miss. It actually says `code` in it. Twice in fact. Shouldn't you have read this before asking me if I had attempted more coding than the google font link? Twice?

Comment: Please take a look at Mailchimps typography guidlines. With a custom font not everything is possible, also support across email clients is limited http://templates.mailchimp.com/design/typography/